# Passing an additional argument to an event handler

Tags: c#

I have an event handler that accept the following event signature (this is from a third party library, so I cannot change the event handler):

```
Task handleEvent(SomeEventArgs args)
```

I register my handler like this:

```
eventProcessor.ProcessEventsAsync += handleEvent;
```

And implement the method like this:

```
private async Task handleEvent(SomeEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Data.Test == parameterValue) {}
}
```

The problem is that I want to find a way to pass `parameterValue` into the handler.  I realise I can do this by storing it as a field or property on the class, but wondered if there was a way to pass it directly.

Comment: You could do something like: `eventProcessor.ProcessEventsAsync += (s, e) => handleEvent(e, extraParameter);` But be aware that this will require changes where you unsubscribe as well, as you need to store the reference to your handler and reuse it when unsubscribing.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen and the extra parameter still needs to be known to the handler - e.g. using a field or property, which OP is trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lambda function if you have the parameter available at subscription:

```
...
{
    eventProcessor.ProcessEventsAsync += (arg) => handleEvent(arg, parameterValue);
}

private async Task handleEvent(SomeEventArgs args, object parameter)
{
    if (args.Data.Test == parameter) {}
}
```

Just change `object` to your type.

Answer (score 1):

It is the library that raises the event that passes arguments to the handler. If that library doesn't support it (e.g. by giving you some object property you can set on it that it will then give back to you when it raises the event) then you have to go the way you've proposed; the handling class retains the knowledge and uses it when the event is raised

Answer (score 0):

You can change the signature of your method and define a field which is a delegate of this method:

```
private Func<SomeEventArgs,string,Task> handleEventDelegate = handleEvent;
private async Task handleEvent(SomeEventArgs args, string parameterValue)
{
    if (args.Data.Test == parameterValue) {}
}
```

The you can subscribe and subscribe your event:

```
eventProcessor.ProcessEventsAsync += handleEventDelegate;
eventProcessor.ProcessEventsAsync -= handleEventDelegate;
```